# Where can I find a map from font font face names to filenames?

Tags: fonts, truetype

I'm trying to write a Java program that finds the TTF for a font face given its name. For example, inputting "Times New Roman" on my Windows machine would return the path "C:\Windows\Fonts\times.ttf".

Most other font face names are abbreviated in a similar manner in the name of their TTF file. Is there a standard somewhere that I can use to map font face names to corresponding TTF filenames predictably?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that the *name* of the font is defined within the *contents* of the font file, so there's no reason there should be any relation with the name of the font file itself.

In Windows XP the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts` lists all the permanent installed system fonts. You can enumerate this list of font files, opening each one in turn and if it is a ttf you can get the `checkSumAdjustment` from its `head` table. Build a list of items, each item containing a pair of values - the font file name and the checksum value.

Then when you later realize a font, call `GetFontData` on it and read the `head` table and find the `checkSumAdjustment` for that font. Then look it up in the list you made earlier.

Comment: The specified registry entry still exists in Windows 10 so this technique should still work.