# Getting TrueType font "post" table from font name

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, truetype

I am trying to extract the "post" table from an installed TrueType font, which I know only by name. How can I achieve this?

I have seen the [`GetFontData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getfontdata) function, which seems to do almost exactly what I want, except that it gets the font data from the device context's currently loaded font. In my case though I do not have a device context, only the font name.
Additionally I have seen similar queries such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2227264/7064452), for looking up and retrieving the entire font file, but this seems unnecessarily inefficient and long-winded, given that Windows *can* already load and parse the font data (as we see for `GetFontData`). Furthermore I don't need the whole file, just the "post" table. Is there really no way except implementing it all myself?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for. If GetFontData(...) gives you what you want then select the font into an HDC and call it.

Comment: @jwezorek But having a HDC implies setting up and/or binding to some sort of rendering context, no? Which I don't have and don't need. I'm not doing anything like that, I don't even have a window.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "post" table?

Comment: It's one of the "tables" in the TrueType font file format, identified by the string "post"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* call GetFontData(...) without having a window or GUI, e.g. from a command line program, by just making a dummy device context on the fly and selecting a font into it

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <vector>

std::vector<unsigned char> GetFontDataByName(const wchar_t* font_name)
{
    HDC hdc = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);

    auto font = CreateFont(0, 0, 0, 0,
        FW_NORMAL, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
        ANSI_CHARSET, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS,
        CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DEFAULT_QUALITY,
        DEFAULT_PITCH,
        font_name);
    SelectObject(hdc, font);
    auto num_bytes = GetFontData(hdc, 0, 0, NULL, 0);
    std::vector<unsigned char> font_data(num_bytes);
    auto result = GetFontData(hdc, 0, 0, &(font_data[0]), num_bytes);

    DeleteDC(hdc);

    return font_data;
}

int main()
{
    auto font_data = GetFontDataByName(L"Times New Roman");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: From [CreateFont](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createfontw): *"Because available fonts can vary from system to system, do not assume that the selected font is always the same as the requested font. For example, if you request a font named Palatino, but no such font is available on the system, the font mapper will substitute a font that has similar attributes but a different name."*

Comment: OP states that the font is installed and he only has its name. Given that it is installed CreateFont is guaranteed to create some version of it, there could however be multiple versions, I guess. Youd have to distinguish there by taking more care in the other parameters you provide to CreateFont betyond the font name because they will affect the matching logic